# Metro apps closing even though plenty of RAM available

Tags: windows-8

even though I have a few GB of RAM free at all times, the 4 metro apps I constantly have open (twitter, world clock, the news app and financial times) all occasionally (maybe after a few hours or I don't know if it has anything to do with standby/wake) will close, and then I must restart them all.

I assume windows 8 metro thinks it needs to reclaim memory, so is there any way to increase the memory limit at which metro kills these apps? It's quite annoying...

Comment: You need to confirm they are not closing because you are going into standby mode.

Comment: would that be normal behaviour? metro apps closing just because I shut the lid of laptop?

Comment: depends on your power configuration settings